# Flutter - Android app shows just a blank screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Android app shows just a blank screen. Below is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

import 'screens/home_screen.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final cameras = await availableCameras();
  final camera = cameras.first;

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'DEMO',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: HomePage(
      title: 'DEMO',
      camera: camera,
    ),
  ));
}
```

Error message

```
D/FlutterActivity( 3535): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 3535): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 3535): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 3535): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterView( 3535): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@dccf1d3
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 3535): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
E/flutter ( 3535): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
E/flutter ( 3535): If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
E/flutter ( 3535): If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.
E/flutter ( 3535): #0      defaultBinaryMessenger.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:76:7)
E/flutter ( 3535): #1      defaultBinaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:89:4)
E/flutter ( 3535): #2      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:140:62)
E/flutter ( 3535): #3      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:35)
E/flutter ( 3535): #4      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:335:40)
E/flutter ( 3535): #5      availableCameras (package:camera/camera.dart:81:10)
E/flutter ( 3535): #6      main (package:idocr/main.dart:8:25)
E/flutter ( 3535): #7      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:239:25)
E/flutter ( 3535): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter ( 3535): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter ( 3535): #10     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
E/flutter ( 3535): #11     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1502:12)
E/flutter ( 3535): #12     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231:5)
E/flutter ( 3535): #13     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:307:19)
E/flutter ( 3535): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
E/flutter ( 3535):
```

Comment: You should remove android tag as it is not relevant here.

Comment: well if you remove your async function it works fine so my guess is ``availableCameras()`` is failing to return

Comment: @wcyankees424 so whats the updated code?

Comment: provide `flutter doctor -v` from your terminal, plus device you test that on

Comment: You still having issues with this

Comment: Please check my updated question with the error message given.

Comment: what flutter branch are you running on

Comment: well thats because you don't have ``WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

import 'screens/home_screen.dart';

Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final cameras = await availableCameras();
  final camera = cameras.first;

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'OCR Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: HomePage(
      title: 'OCR Text Recognition',
      camera: camera,
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a route to your `HomePage` like this

```
runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'DEMO',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(
        title: 'DEMO',
        camera: camera,
      ),
      routes: {
        HomePage.routeName: (ctx) => HomePage(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

then in your home page widget

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'homePage';
```

Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: let me try first

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Comment: Please check my updated question with the error message given.

Answer (score 0):

You should request permissions before calling on availableCameras. That's why the screen is blank. Below is my code for using Camera. Get permissions before you call availableCameras. Also go to your android manifest file in flutter app and add the permissions there as well.

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPermissions();
  }

  
  Future getPermissions() async {

    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissions =
    await [
      Permission.storage, Permission.camera, Permission.microphone
    ].request();

    if (permissions[Permission.storage] == PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permissions[Permission.camera] == PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permissions[Permission.microphone] == PermissionStatus.granted) {

      await getCameras();

    }
  }

 Future getCameras() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {

      /*if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});*/

      setState(() {

        isPermitted = true;

      });


    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you show full code for this? I don't think it's a complete code compare to my question above.

Comment: Please check my updated question with the error message given.